# NativeScript: Still getting "Android SDK Is Not Installed Error" when running TNS Doctor

Tags: nativescript

I am having a hard time getting setup for Android.  I've been exclusively doing iOS without a problem for over a year but after installing Android Studio, creating an emulator, downloading the SDK, I am still getting this error: `✖ WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.`  I checked my bash profile and have pasted it below.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

**~/.bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have installed the Android SDK with Android Studio, your ANDROID_HOME path should be `/Users/$userid/Library/Android/sdk`

[source](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x)

I had the same issue too. Everything worked for me after switching to the path I mentioned above.